# How does ACRA catch all of an app's exceptions?

Tags: android, acra

Do you know how [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) - the Android Crash reporting framework - works under the hood?

How does it hook-in to catch exceptions and errors? Is it using some global try/catch block to detect errors?

And does it affect performance and battery life by doing this?

Comment: People downvoted your question because you've linked directly to the source where you could have researched the question yourself, but I think it's still valuable to have a question like this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not proficient enough in Java to understand it well and fast and it's possible that someone has already done this research and will make a better explanation. I guess that's what the forum is all about. In the end, everyone can think of solutions and solve the problems by himself, but it will take more time and effort. Not that it's the better way, but sometimes I don't have enough capacity and time to dig deeper into everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACRA works by setting up a default exception handler on the main thread. You can see that in the source code [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/ErrorReporter.java#L200):

```
   mDfltExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
   Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
```

It sets itself as the default uncaught exception handler at this point. Java will call this handler if there are any Exceptions that are thrown that are never caught by any `try/catch` block.

Since it's not really an active daemon or process, but rather part of your code (assuming you call `ACRA.init()`), it doesn't actually impact performance or battery life at all.